# Safer Handles in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, io, functional-programming

I felt a bit insecure when using Haskell Handles. Namely, I'm looking for two features (maybe they are already there and in that case please forgive my ignorance).

1. When I've obtained a handle (e.g., returned by `Network.accept`), which
   is both readable and writable, I wish to convert them into a pair of
   **read-only** and **write-only** handles such that writing to a read-only
   handle won't type check and vice versa. (Perhaps one can achieve
   this using phantom types and wraps around IO functions?)
2. In a concurrent setting, I found that it is possible for **multiple threads** to write to the same handle, which gives rise to quite nasty consequences. How could one prevent that through the type system (if possible) or at least get notified of such case via thrown exception during run-time?

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider using the [network conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-conduit) package. It describes a network application as something that is given two "endpoints" - one sink pushes data into a socket and one source that reads data from the socket:

```
type Application m = AppData m -> m ()

data AppData m Source -- ...
appSource :: AppData m -> Source m ByteStringSource
appSink :: AppData m -> Sink ByteString m ()
```

This cleanly separates the writing and the reading part. Now you can do whatever you like with such a source and a sink, even passing each to a different thread and processing input and output separately. Of course, each of them can only read or write, depending on what endpoint you give to it.

If you want to enforce single-threaded processing, you can restrict yourself to implement your program components as `Conduit ByteString m ByteString`. Such a conduit can be aseily turned into an `Application`s like

```
asApp :: MonadIO m => Conduit ByteString m ByteString -> Application m
asApp cond ad = appSource ad $= cond $$ appSink ad
```

But a conduit can only request data using `await` and write output using `yield`,  otherwise has no access to any kind of handles and never sees any of its endpoints, so it can't expose or leak them anywhere.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the [safer-file-handles](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safer-file-handles) library does what you want. The first part is handled pretty clearly. The concurrency-safety appears to be handled by `RegionT` from the [regions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regions-0.11) library. I haven't used this at all, but it looks like a pretty common approach.